# __dirname always returns "/" no matter which file I console log it out

Tags: javascript, node.js, dirname

```
console.log("__dirname: ", __dirname);
```

no matter which file or nested file I place the above code in, it always logs "/".

Comment: Given your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74735141/1048572), it seems there's something seriously messed up with your nodejs installation, but we don't have enough details to help you with this.

Comment: This node project is only acting this way when I import it from another node project.

Comment: It is actually symlink into the nodule_modules folder of the importing project.

Comment: `__dirname` is the same for the entire module